# Tosca puzzle 73589 solved with RBFW. (failed: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (<string>)

Tags: python, robotframework, puzzle

In order to help te test community understand the differences in test tools, I try to make a range just like Flur-Funk did with Tosca.
(I used Tosca for a x time in projects)

So now I solve the same puzzles but then with Robot Framework.
(I will put them online in Youtube later)

So this one (hard) puzzle I get stuck:
This is what I got so far:

```
    *** Settings ***
# https://robotframework-browser.org/
Library   Browser
Library   DateTime
Library    Collections
Library    String
#Library    SeleniumLibrary
#Library   SeleniumLibrary

# https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html
# pip install DateTime

*** Variables ***
@{VALUES}   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |

*** Test Cases ***
Example Test 73589
    Browser.Open Browser      https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/73589
    ${rijmetgetallen}=  GET TEXT    id=array
    LOG TO CONSOLE    ${rijmetgetallen}
    ${stripped}=  STRIP STRING     ${rijmetgetallen}  characters=[,\'n]
    ${converted}=  CONVERT TO LIST  ${stripped}
    FOR ${var}  IN  ${stripped}
        Run Keyword If  '${var}' == '1' Continue For Loop
        Click  id=b1
        LOG TO CONSOLE    ${var}
        # ELSE  Click  id=tech  
    END
    Click  id=button1
    Click  id=button2
    Get Text         xpath=//body    *=   You solved this automation problem.

# used resources:
# https://www.tutorialspoint.com/robot_framework/robot_framework_working_with_variables.htm
```

which results in the log:

```
Example Test 73589                                                    3
2
5
1
9
4
8
6
7
| FAIL |
Evaluating expression ''3
2
5
1
9
4
8
6
7' == '1'' failed: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (<string>, line 1)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0012 Test 73589                                                       | FAIL |
```

How would you solve this one?
How to get past the error?

the solution for the Tosca tool can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcsuH8Q1x60

Comment: `${converted}` is not the list you expect, `Convert To List` did not magically broke down your string of numbers to a list where each member is a an individual number. Hint - use `Split String` for that. Your algorithm for solving the puzzle is not right; what does your loop do - it runs as many times as there are numbers, and clicks Swap (presumably, if id=b1 is that) - if the current number is not 1; and stops. That's not bubble sort (it uses an inner loop), nor how this html page can be solved (with one high-enough loop and 2 condition checks).Finally the syntax of the `Get Text` is wrong.

Comment: I stand corrected for the `Get Text` comment, didn't realize you are using the Browser library that has asserts baked in the keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution - don't forget to credit me in the video ;)

It uses SeleniumLibrary, both xpath & css selectors, FOR & IF blocks, and direct variable access (`$var` vs `${var}`).

```
Tosca 73589
    Open Browser        https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/73589
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath://div[@class="num"]    # so the page is fully loaded 
    ${total numbers}=   Get Element Count   xpath://div[@class="num"]
    ${iterations}=      Evaluate        ${total numbers} * ${total numbers}

    ${done}=    Set Variable    ${False}
    FOR     ${i}    IN RANGE    ${iterations}

        ${n1}=      Get Text    css:div.bubble > div:nth-child(1)
        ${n2}=      Get Text    css:div.bubble > div:nth-child(2)

        IF      int($n1) > int($n2)
            Click Element       xpath://button[@id="button1"]
            Wait Until Element Does Not Contain         css:div.bubble > div:nth-child(1)       ${n1}       # to be sure the UI has redrawn the numbers
            # The list is going to change to ordered only after a swap,
            # just advancing won't ever solve it; thus check for the "done" text value only here.
            ${text solved}=     Get Text        css:a#sample
            ${done}=    Run Keyword And Return Status       Should Not Be Equal As Strings      ${text solved}      KEEP SORTING
        END

        IF  not $done
            Click Element       xpath://button[@id="button2"]
        ELSE
            Exit For Loop
        END
    END
    Run Keyword If      not $done     Fail    The list was not sorted for the maximum iterations!

    [Teardown]      Close Browser
```

There is a corner case that will make it not work - leaving this to you ;)

Comment: Thank you so much Todor! that is very kind of you! For 20 puzzles I have a solution that works, some very elegant and pretty, others get the job done but that's it. Yes I will certainly mention you! One of the most important things I'd like to show is that in some cases Tosca is super fast and easy to get a puzzle done, but in other cases RobotFrameWork is far more straight forward or faster, and that's exactly what I want to point out.

Comment: Tested the solution: Is this the corner case?:        StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <div class="num"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Comment: Nah, not just that @LTL - this one comes because the page triggers "loaded", but elements are still drawn. A "wait until" on it will clear out the error. The corner case I'm hinting at is - what will happen if on page landing the list is already ordered? ;)